# base64 leads to "TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly" error

Tags: python, json, base64, encode

I'm trying to send out a JSON message but the device I'm sending to requires the API Key to be encoded with base64. This is all being tied into a project called [Home Assistant](http://www.home-assistant.io)

Here is my code:

```
import logging
import requests
import base64

import voluptuous as vol

from homeassistant.components.notify import ATTR_MESSAGE, \
PLATFORM_SCHEMA, BaseNotificationService

from homeassistant.const import CONF_API_KEY, CONF_HOST
import homeassistant.helpers.config_validation as cv

api_key = CONF_API_KEY
NOTE_URL = 'http://' + CONF_HOST  + ':8080/api/v2/device/notifications'

encoded_api = base64.b64encode(api_key.encode('ascii'))
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded_api,
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    }

data = '{"priority": "warning", "icon_type": "none", "model": \
     {"frames": [{"icon": "i3579", "text": ' + ATTR_MESSAGE + '}], \
         "sound": {"category": "notifications", "id": "positive4"}}}'

requests.post(NOTE_URL, headers=headers, data=data)
```

On boot, this gives the `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly` error on the `'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded_api,` line.

I've tried calling it implicitly with `encoded_api = (api_key).decode("UTF-8"), I've tried io.StringIO, and others to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to use a bytes literal, e.g. `b'Basic ' + encoded_api,` but I'm not sure that wouldn't cause a conniption later down the line.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick! I'll have to do more testing, but for right now it seems good.

Thanks!